# Looking for better way of making a single list of forwards and reverse directory names for matching with files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Here is the code I'm currently working with.

```
Input = ['cat','tab','mad dog']
output = [x for x in Input] + [' '.join(x.split(' ')[::-1]) for x in Input if len(x.split())>1]
```

It works fine and is pretty fast but I don't think it reads particularly well.

Is there anything better that wouldn't sacrifice speed, as that is the most important thing for its use?

Why? its actually for searching directories where the name (one or two words) may have been typed in reverse.

```
output= ['cat', 'tab', 'mad dog', 'dog mad']
```

This is the correct result but I'm pretty sure there is a better way of getting there.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a list? Might a set be more appropriate?

Comment: a list is returned by the iterator which is creating the list of folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as #slothrop commented

```
Input = ['cat','tab','mad dog']

output = Input + [' '.join(x.split()[::-1]) for x in Input if ' ' in x]
```

or

```
Input.append(*[' '.join(x.split()[::-1]) for x in Input if ' ' in x])
```

or

```
output = Input + [' '.join(reversed(x.split())) for x in Input if ' ' in x]

#['cat', 'tab', 'mad dog', 'dog mad']
```

Comment: yep that is slightly better, the Input on its own part is due to the list of directories actually coming from somewhere else so I replaced it with Input but I get the point.

Comment: `append` returns None, so `output = Input.append(*blah)` won't do what you want it to.

Comment: thanks both, I had completely overlooked "if ' ' in x" so that has been a big help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, flipping the problem round a bit, is to define your collection of target directories as a **set of sets of words**. A set is inherently unordered, so there's no need to go through every combination. So this would scale up quite well if you have names with more than 2 words.

Then to check whether a directory is of interest to you, turn the directory name into a set of words and see if that's in the target set.

For example:

```
# 1) Creating the target word sets
input_words = ['cat','tab','mad dog']
target_word_sets = {frozenset(x.split()) for x in input_words}

# 2) Checking a directory name against the target word sets, wherever in the program this is needed
my_dir_names = ['cat', 'mad cat', 'mad dog', 'dog mad']
for dn in my_dir_names:
    is_in_target = set(dn.split()) in target_word_sets
    print(f'{dn}: {is_in_target}')
```

which prints:

```
cat: True
mad cat: False
mad dog: True
dog mad: True
```

Note, when using a set of sets, the inner sets must be hashable, hence the use of `frozenset` rather than plain old `set`.

Comment: ok I get your example but my "Input" is from an iterator which creates the list of directories in the location im interested in so im not sure how I can end up with my_dir_names in advance as the list may change?

Comment: You don't need it in advance: this was just an example to show that the check works :) Wherever in your existing approach you would have done `if some_dir_name in output:` , with this approach you'd do `if set(some_dir_name.split()) in target_word_sets:`

Comment: right Ive done a few tests with that and it surprised me how well it worked even using something like os.listdir(path) to create the input and test it with folders spelled backwards and forwards. great idea would never have thought of doing that. 
However I think I will go with the first idea as I can just see what is going on but many thanks it will give me something to think about in future.